# How can I add custom HTML to pyqtlet?

Tags: javascript, pyqt, leaflet, pyqtlet

My actual problem is much more specific, but I think a more general answer will help me to cope with future needs.

I actually need to enable [`leaflet-extras`](https://github.com/leaflet-extras/leaflet-providers) plugin for `leaflet` underlying `pyqtlet`.

Documentation says:

> Download leaflet-providers.js and include it in your page after including Leaflet, e.g.:

```
<head>
  ...
  <script src="http://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="js/leaflet-providers.js"></script>
</head>
```

and then:

```
// add Stamen Watercolor to map.
L.tileLayer.provider('Stamen.Watercolor').addTo(map);
```

Of course all this is in the assumption you are writing a JavaScript app while I am in `pyqtlet` environment.

I tried to cope in a very ugly way:

- downloaded `leaflet-providers.js` to my `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtlet/web/modules`
- added the line `<script src="modules/leaflet-providers.js"></script>` to my `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyqtlet/web/map.html`
- used `self.map.runJavaScript("L.tileLayer.provider('Stamen.Watercolor'). addTo(map)")` to activate the desired `tileLayer`

This **actually works**, but I'm sure there's a cleaner way to achieve the same.

Any hint welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trivial solution is to read the .js and run it:

```
with open("/path/of/leaflet-providers.js") as f:
    self.map.runJavaScript(f.read())
    self.map.runJavaScript("L.tileLayer.provider('Stamen.Watercolor'). addTo(map)")
```

Another similar option is to use document.createElement:

```py
with open("/path/of/leaflet-providers.js") as f:
    code = f.read()
    SCRIPT = """
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    script.text = `%s`;
    """ % (
        code,
    )
    self.map.runJavaScript(SCRIPT)
    self.map.runJavaScript(
        "L.tileLayer.provider('Stamen.Watercolor'). addTo(map)"
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. With first solution (seems simpler) will I have javascript code loaded? I mean: if I later need to use the same plugin again can I just `self.map.runJavaScript("L.tileLayer.provider('Another.choice'). addTo(map)")` or do I need to read the `leaflet-providers.js` again?

Comment: @ZioByte I haven't tested it but you probably don't have to upload it, test and verify. The second option I think could not have that drawback, both are simple ways, there is nothing magical.